# C++/Qt Threads error without using threads

Tags: c++, qt, uitableview, user-interface, qt4

I am using a special form of the qt framework and it will look a bit complicated. But do not worry. It is the same as the original framework of qt. (And no I can't change it)

My intention of this program is to load a table in a `tableview` from the ui. The `tableview` should have as many rows and text as files that are in a directory. I take all files in the directory and put an filter on them. Only the selected one are counted and used afterwards.

And now to my problem:
I want to display the table like an Excel table: it should highlight the cell where my cursor (in my example it is an counter which goes up and down) stands right now (Currently I do not have a cursor, so I have to use a self-created "cursor". You will see it in the program what I mean).
I use a `QStandardItemModel` to display it and a `QStandardItem` to define it. 
Because I want to change the color of the cells I use an `QStandardItem` array to save the cells one by one.

form.h:

```
#ifndef FORM_H
#define FORM_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QTextTable>
#include <QFont>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDir>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QStandardItem>
#include <QBrush>


namespace Ui {
class Form;
}

class Form : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Form(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Form();

    void my_setCFGFromDirectory();
    void my_Highlighted(int, bool);
    void my_loadCFG(int);


private:
    Ui::Form *ui;

    QFile file;
    QTextStream textstream;
    QDir directory;
    QString filename;
    QStringList stringlist;
    QStringList filter;
    QStandardItemModel *model;
    QStandardItem *tableitem;
    QStandardItem* pointerTableitem[];

    int max_files;
    int w_counter;
    bool check1;
    bool check2;
    bool check3;
};

#endif // FORM_H
```

and the
form.cpp

```
#include "form.h"
#include "ui_form.h"
#include "rbobject.h"

Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Form::~Form()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Form::my_Highlighted(int actual_count, bool modus){
    if(modus == 1){
        w_counter = 0;
        while(w_counter < max_files){
            if(w_counter == actual_count){
                pointerTableitem[w_counter]->setBackground(QBrush(QColor(130,180,255)));
            }
            w_counter++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        w_counter = 0;
        while(w_counter < max_files){
            pointerTableitem[w_counter]->setBackground(QBrush(QColor(255,255,255)));
            w_counter++;
        }
    }
}



void Form::my_setCFGFromDirectory(){
    directory.setPath("/etc/rosenbauer/CFG-Files");
    filter << "*_CFG.ini";
    stringlist = directory.entryList(filter);      //takes the selected files and wriths them in a filelist
    max_files = stringlist.count();               //Counts the selected files
    pointerTableitem [max_files];
    memset(pointerTableitem, 0, max_files*sizeof(int)); //The compiler can not see how many elements should be in the array at the time he constructs the array.
                                                        //So you have to use this to tell the compiler, how many elements it should create

    model = new QStandardItemModel(max_files, 1, this);             //Rows , Columns , this
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, new QStandardItem(QString("CFG-Files"))); //Column , QStandarditem...name

    for(w_counter = 0; w_counter != max_files; w_counter++){
        tableitem = new QStandardItem();
        tableitem->setBackground(QBrush(QColor(255,255,255)));
        tableitem->setText(QString(stringlist[w_counter]));     //Wriths text in the cell
        qDebug() << tableitem->text();

        pointerTableitem[w_counter] = tableitem;    //Stacks the tableitems in a filelist
        model->setItem(w_counter, 0, tableitem);    //Row, Column , tableitem...text
    }
    w_counter = 0;

    //pointerTableitem[2]->setBackground(QBrush(QColor(130,180,255))); //Test

    ui->TableConfig->setModel(model);   //Sets the table into the UI
}



void Form::my_loadCFG(int file_position){


    check1 = 0;
    check2 = 0;

    directory.setPath("/etc/rosenbauer/etc/rosenbauer");
    check1 = directory.remove("SA008_890560-001_CFG.ini");
    check2 = directory.remove("reparsed/SA008_890560-001_CFG.ini_reparsed");

    if(check1 && check2){
        filename = pointerTableitem[file_position]->text();
        check3 = QFile::copy("/etc/rosenbauer/CFG-Files/"+filename, "/etc/rosenbauer/SA008_890560-001_CFG.ini");

        if(!check3){
            qDebug() << "Error! Could not copy new CFG-file into directory";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Error! Could not delete running CFG-file(s) from directory";
    }


}
```

The main header rbobject45000.h

```
#ifndef RbObject45000_H
#define RbObject45000_H

#include "rbobject.h"
#include "form.h"
class RbObject45000 : public RbObject{


public:
    RbObject45000();
    RbObject45000(qint32 rbObjectId, RDataObject *dataobject, qint32 style, QObject *parent = 0);
    RbObject45000(qint32 rbObjectId, qint32 style, qint32 prio, QObject *parent);

    bool entered_ui;
    bool entered_key;
    short counter;

    short w_count;
    short delay_count;

    short max_files;
    short begin;
    short end;

    Form *f;



    void exec();

~RbObject45000();
};

#endif // RbObject45000_H
```

And this is the main:
rbobject45000.cpp

```
RbObject45000::RbObject45000(qint32 rbObjectId, qint32 style, qint32 prio, QObject *parent):
    RbObject(rbObjectId, style, prio, parent){

    entered_ui = 0;
    entered_key = 0;

    counter = 0;
    w_count = 1; //... whilecounter
    delay_count = 0; //... delay for the deadtime

    max_files = 0;
    begin = 0;
    end = 0;

    f= new Form(); //f...name of the displayed UI
}


void RbObject45000::exec(){

//Opens the file on the display
    if(getKey(RB_KEY_9) && getKey(RB_KEY_7) && entered_ui ==0){
        f->show();
        entered_ui = 1;


        // Geting the Files from Directory
        f->my_setCFGFromDirectory();
    }


// Prescind them file in the table
    if(entered_ui == 1 && delay_count == 2){

        if(getKey(RB_KEY_7)){
            counter--;
            entered_key = 1;
            if(counter < 0){
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
        else if(getKey(RB_KEY_9)){
            counter++;
            entered_key = 1;
            if(counter > max_files){
                counter = max_files;
            }
        }


        if(entered_key == 1){
            while(w_count <= max_files){
                f->my_Highlighted(w_count, 0); //Cell , not highlighted
                w_count++;
            }
            w_count = 0;
            f->my_Highlighted(counter,1);  //Cell , highlighted
            entered_key = 0;
        }
        delay_count = 0;

    }
    else if(delay_count == 2){  //if delay == 2 and nobody hit a button
        delay_count = 0;
    }
    delay_count++;


    //Load the coosen file as programm-config in
    if(entered_ui == 1){
        if(getKey(RB_KEY_8)){
           f->my_loadCFG(counter);
        }
    }

}
```

(RB_KEY_7-9 are buttons of a hardware-module, only have to click them)
So if I do it like this, the program will compile and start. If I press the buttons and the program run into the `my_setCFGFromDirectory()` it exits the window and stop running, but if the `QStandardItem pointerTableitem` is declared in the `my_setCFGFromDirectory()` everything works fine (but the `pointerTableitem` needs to be `private`).

The errors I get are:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is Form(0x167498), parent's thread is QThread(0x1414e8), current thread is QThread(0x15d2d8)
Segmentation fault
```

It appears to say I use a thread (I'm sure I don't). But I know it has something to do with `pointerTableitem` and the declaration in the header and cpp.

Comment: You say you are not using thread but `RbObject45000::exec()` seems likely suspicious to be a function that overrides `QThread::exec()`. Can you post the definition of `RbObject4500` ?

Comment: I edited it :) But it has'nt any problem in the 45000 file. This file works fine. Only the "form.h" and "form.cpp" are the toublemakers

Comment: posted an answer based on what I can get out of this. And you are using a thread;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken the problem lies here:

```
model = new QStandardItemModel(max_files, 1, this);
```

You try to create a `QStandardItemModel` passing your `Form` instance `this` as a parent, the form was created on the main thread, this call apparently happens on another thread (the edits you made were not enough, it is still unclear if `RbObject` inherits `QThread` but you could check that yourself) and thus the error message.

Why not call the function on the main thread? Instead of doing this

```
f->show();
entered_ui = 1;

// Geting the Files from Directory
f->my_setCFGFromDirectory();
```

in a different thread, make a slot/signal pair for the `Form` class, put this code in the slot and fire the connected signal from `RbObject45000::exec()`. It is not correct to do UI manipulation from a non-UI trhead.

Comment: 1. Yheea. I think e get it what you are trying to say. I'll chang it. Thanks alot ^^ :)

2. Ähm. So you mean the `f->show()` funktion is in the wrong file?
If so I can tell you that it is like this and i can't change it. I'm just now writhing my final year project and the company I'm working with says so. And yhea. Thats the thing :)

Comment: Well, `f->show()` is not the main issue (I am not aware of the Qt internals, maybe it checks from which thread it is called and inside actually emits a signal to the main thread when you call it from a non gui thread), `f->my_setCFGFromDirectory()` is. The issue you are getting is because you CREATE an object with a parent in a wrong thread. If you can either 1) move all the stuff that is in `my_setCFGFromDirectory()` to a slot of `Form` and emit a signal for that slot in `my_setCFGFromDirectory()` you should be fine.

Comment: Hm. Hm. You mean everything in `my_setCFGFromDirectory` or only the declaration things?

Comment: Everything, how do you imagine it would work if you would just put a part of it in the slot? Let's put it this way - create a new slot `Form::my_setCFGFromDirectorySlot` that has all the code from `Form::my_setCFGFromDirectory`, create a new signal for `Form` called let say `my_SetCFGFromDirectorySignal`, connect the signal to the slot, and then in `Form::my_setCFGFromDirectory` just do `emit my_SetCFGFromDirectorySignal();` instead of the current logic.

Comment: Hm. Not exactly what I need but it works :) Thanks alot :)

Comment: @Schausi how does it differ from what you need? I'd say this is the correct approach.

Comment: No. It`s the solution I searched for. But it isn't the way my company want it. So you have'nt done anything wrong. :) 
P.s. Thanks again :)